# Assertion failed Error when running a compiled GCTB software on Mac (file DenseCoeffsBase.h, line 410)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, bayesian, genetics, apple-m2

I am running GCTB (A tool for Genome-wide Complex Trait Bayesian analysis) software through the terminal. I have a Mac Apple M2 and had to compile the software from its source code (written in C++). It was running smoothly until I got the following Error:

Assertion failed: (index >= 0 && index < size()), function operator[], file DenseCoeffsBase.h, line 410.
(the errors appears following trying to read the --gwas-summary file)

My code:
/Desktop/gctb_2.05beta_scr/scr/gctb --sbayes C --ldm CLSA.ldm.full --overlap --gwas-summary GWAS_SS.ma --pi 0.0001 --hsq 0.001 --seed 1990 --chain-length 10000 --burn-in 5000 --no-mcmc-bin --robust --out-freq 100 --thin 10 --out Dec5

I dont have much experience with computer systems, and would appreciate the help. Thanks!

I need to know if the error pertains to the GCTB its self or the gwas ss file.